# .htaccess nginx качает php

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

```
RewriteRule ^auth_callback([^?]*)$ index.php?route=common/social/login/facebook/int_callback&code=$1 [QSA,L]


location /auth_callback {
  rewrite ^/auth_callback([^?]*)$ /index.php?route=common/social/login/facebook/int_callback&code=$1 break;
}
```

Не работает - скачивает index.php

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте задать этот вопрос и на РутКод. Даже, наверное, можно здесь не удалять - не очень понятно, к чему вопрос имеет большее отношение

Comment: Если убрать правило из .htaccess , то работает нормально?

Answer (score 1):

файлы `.htaccess` обрабатываются, насколько мне известно, лишь одной реализацией http-сервера — *apache*.

программа *nginx* **не обрабатывает** эти файлы. всё необходимое должно быть указано в конфигурации *nginx*.